# Create a looped audio from a certain part of audio using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

How can we create a looped audio with ffmpeg from an audio file?

The command used for a looped audio is

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "amovie=audio.wav:loop=3" out.wav
```

but this creates a looped file of the whole audio, not a part of it.

What I need is: If the audio file is of a duration of 4 mins 30 sec, I want to get part from 2 min 25 sec to 3 min 55 sec, of the audio and loop it

How can I do this?

Comment: The OP (and future readers) got help. That's what we are here for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option 1 — Trimming and looping

You can use the `atrim` filter to first trim your input to the required part, then use the `aloop` filter to loop that section.

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a \
    -filter_complex " \
    [0:a] \
        atrim=0:3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS, \
        asetrate=48000,aloop=2:size=3*48000 \
    [outa]" \
    -map "[outa]" \
    -c:a aac \
    out.m4a
```

In the above example, note the following settings:

- the input is cut from 0 to 3 seconds with `atrim`
- the cut part is played 3⨉ (`aloop=2` – you get the original audio once, and two loops)
- the size of the loop is set with `size=3*48000`
- the audio codec is AAC with the default quality options (`-c:a aac`)

If you want a different duration, e.g. from 5 to 10 seconds, change `atrim=5:10`, and change `size=5*48000`.

Unfortunately, the `aloop` filter requires setting the size of the looped portion in samples—in our case, that's 3 seconds ⨉ 48,000 samples. Since you don't know the input sample rate, you have to set it to 48,000 Hz first with the `asetrate` filter.

If there's an easier way, I'd be glad to know about it, but unfortunately the `amovie` input source does not allow trimming on the fly.

#### Option 2 — Looping, then stopping

An alternative might be:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.m4a \
    -filter_complex " \
    [0:a]asetrate=48000,aloop=1:size=3*48000[outa]" \
    -map "[outa]" \
    -t 6 \
    -c:a aac \
    out.m4a
```

Here, the input is not trimmed; it's just the loop size that determines the length of the loop. But then you have to specify the total output duration (i.e, 6 seconds) with `-t`. If you want a different offset, use `ffmpeg -ss <timestamp> -i input.m4a`, where `<timestamp>` is the seek point.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you look at another of my question which is based on loop and trim concept of ffmpeg https://superuser.com/questions/1391908/add-part-of-audio-with-loop-to-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using a complex pipeline you can also do this with a simple filter chain:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af 'atrim=2*60+25:duration=80,aloop=3:size=44100*80' out.wav
```