# Add part of audio with loop to video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a video 5 min 30 seconds long and an audio 4 mins 30 seconds long

I want to add part of audio(part of audio from 1 min 25 sec to 1 min 47 sec) to video(part of video from 2 min 30 sec to 3 min 55 sec)

What I have been able to do is loop audio and add it to video with this command:

```
"-y","-i",j, "-filter_complex",
"amovie="+audio+":loop=1000," +
"asetpts=N/SR/TB,atrim=0:85,adelay=150000|150000,apad," +
"aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];" +
"[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=3.5[a2];" +
" [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]",
"-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

However this is the problem I have faced:

It does add audio of 85 sec to video from 2:30 to 3:55, but it starts from 0:00 of audio to 1:25 part of audio.

What I want is to have a 22 sec clip of audio from (1 min 25 sec to 1 min 47 sec part of audio file) and loop it for 85 seconds and add that to video file

How can that be done?

Comment: Please, next time, show the actual command, not the code that you're using to generate the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your audio starts from 0:00 because you have not done any seeking.

Use the `seek_point=...` option for the [`amovie` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amovie) to seek in the file first.

```
amovie=input.m4a:sp=85
```

The above would start the file from 1:25 in (85 seconds).